# If conditions in a loop breaking ffmpeg zoom command

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have built a bash script where I am trying to zoom in an image with ffmpeg, for 10s:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i image0.jpg -filter_complex "scale=-2:10*ih,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=250:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',scale=-2:720"  -y -shortest -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p temp_1.mp4
```

This command is included in a while loop, with two "if" conditions at the beginning of the loop:

```
first=1017 
i=0
while read status author mySource myFormat urlIllustration credit shot_id originalShot categories title_EN length_title_EN text_EN tags_EN title_FR length_title_FR text_FR tags_FR title_BR length_title_BR text_BR tags_BR; do

    if [ $myFormat != "diaporama" ]; then 
        let "i = i + 1"
        continue
    fi

    if [ "$shot_id" -lt "$first" ]; then 
        let "i = i + 1"
        continue
    fi

    rm temp_1.mp4
    ffmpeg -r 25 -i image0.jpg -filter_complex "scale=-2:10*ih,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=250:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)',scale=-2:720"  -y -shortest -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p temp_1.mp4 


    let "i = i + 1"
done <../data.tsv
echo "All done."
```

(I have removed stuff in the loop, this is the minimal code that is able to capture the problem).

Now the weird bug: if I run this code like that, the video I am trying to generate will not be 10s long, only 1-2s long. ffmpeg exits with error "[out_0_0 @ 0x2fa4c00] 100 buffers queued in out_0_0, something may be wrong."

Now if I remove one of the "if" conditions at the beginning of my loop (the first or the second, it doesn't matter), the video will be generated fine and be 10s long.

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net) suggests using `ffmpeg < /dev/null ..`  to [prevent ffmpeg from eating stdin from the while loop](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2095).

Comment: Or just use `-nostdin` global `ffmpeg` option (not sure if that is the issue or not–just mentioning an alternative method).

Comment: @thatotherguy that was the problem and I had never heard of this problem before! Thanks!

Comment: @thatotherguy @LordNeckbeard it looks like removing stdin breaks this other command though: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.mp4 -vf "zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4` (the clip is generated with an infinite number of frames)

Comment: Does it work by itself outside of the script?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes, it works outside of the script

Comment: Does it also fail with `-nostdin` or redirection outside the script?